# Cast possibly undefined boolean to boolean using "!!"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I was wondering - should I cast a possibly undefined boolean variable to boolean using double exclamation mark?

Let's assume we have this interface:

```js
interface Example {
  id: number;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
}
```

Then we have an object of type `Example`:

```js
const object: Example = { id: 1 };
```

Then I use the `isDisabled` property in Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query to determine if data should be downloaded. And here comes the question:

Is this approach:

```js
const { data } = useGetDataQuery(undefined, { skip: object.isDisabled });
```

the same as this approach:

```js
const { data } = useGetDataQuery(undefined, { skip: !!object.isDisabled });
```

?

The `skip` property in `useQuery` hook can be of type `boolean | undefined`, so technically both code snippets will work, but I'm curious if `{ skip: undefined }` would produce the same effect as `{ skip: false }` and wouldn't make any bugs?

Comment: `!` applied to any falsy value returns `true`. Its a coercion. The second `!` has nothing to do with this. There's no `!!` operator

Comment: Why would you set a boolean value to undefined? Undefined is falsy, so if you would check for disabled, you would get false anyway. In that case, I think it's cleaner to just default it to false. But just my preference.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: `!!` is an idiom for converting truthy values to `true` and falsy values to `false`. `!!object.isDisabled` means the same as `!(!object.isDisabled)` or `Boolean(object.isDisabled)` or `object.isDisabled ? true : false`.

Comment: @ruakh I'm aware of that. But the question speaks of it like a single operation and I wanted to clarify.

Comment: 'isDisabled' property could be set or not. I can't set it to false by default (because that would cause some problems with logic in my project), that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @dellus that's fine. There's nothing wrong with your code. You're handling an optional boolean in a proper way and you've reflected that in the type signature as well.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I'm glad there's nothing wrong. Firstly I thought that there's no difference between undefined or false, both are falsy values, but I saw many times that someone used this "!!" operator to cast possibly undefined value and I was wondering "Why? After all, both undefined and false are falsy, so why they did that?"

Comment: @dellus there are APIs that explicitly check for boolean values and `undefined` (or `null`) as semantically distinct.

Comment: It's a good practice to explicitly coerce `undefined` to `false` when you want to treat them in the same fashion. That way, your code will work correctly with strict equality and switch statements, and switch statements among other things. Also, @Pointy is correct. The reason why your code is proper is that you do not wish to differentiate them.

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry but what does this mean? I'm kinda new to this whole IT ;d

Comment: @AluanHaddad "The reason why your code is proper is that you do not wish to differentiate them." - okay, finally which version is proper?

Comment: Do you don't want three value logic? I'm guessing that you don't based on the code you wrote and how this is generally expressed. If you do want distinguish between an `undefined `value and a `false` value and a `true` value, performing different Logic for each case, then you don't want to coerce undefined to `false`.

Comment: @dellus some tools and libraries you may use may explicitly look for `true` or `false` as opposed to making a simple JavaScript "truthy" test. Think of it as being the difference between an assertion that a decision has definitely been made (`true` or `false`) or not (`undefined` or `null`).  Also, `!!` becomes much more obviously meaningful when the "source" value is a number or a string, because it converts `0` or `""` to `false` and other values to `true`.

Comment: I've tagged the question with `rtk-query` and `redux-toolkit` since your question "is this the same" depends on how `useDataQuery()` acts.  If these tags seem wrong/irrelevant to you, please [edit] the question to remove the apparent dependency on third-party libraries so that the code is a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach:
>
> `const { data } = useGetDataQuery(undefined, { skip: object.isDisabled });`
>
> the same as this approach:
>
> `const { data } = useGetDataQuery(undefined, { skip: !!object.isDisabled });` ?

According to the [useQuery type declaration](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) the `skip` is declared to be an optional boolean type.

> ```
> type UseQuery = (
>   arg: any | SkipToken,
>   options?: UseQueryOptions
> ) => UseQueryResult
>
> type UseQueryOptions = {
>   pollingInterval?: number
>   refetchOnReconnect?: boolean
>   refetchOnFocus?: boolean
>   skip?: boolean // <-- optional boolean
>   refetchOnMountOrArgChange?: boolean | number
>   selectFromResult?: (result: UseQueryStateDefaultResult) => any
> }
> ```

This means the query is skipped ***only when*** `skip` has the value `true`, otherwise passing `false` or `undefined` have the same effect, that being the query isn't skipped.

The following are equivalent:

- `skip: object.isDisabled` => `skip: undefined` => query unskipped
- `skip: !!object.isDisabled` => `skip: false` => query unskipped